# For loop to format cells every other 5 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to format a growing table. Assuming the table has 20 rows I want the first 5 and every other 5 after that so 1-5, 11-15 to be a certain color. I tried to achieve this with a for loop.

```
b = 0
For i = 1 To lRow
    a = i - (5 * (i \ 5))
    c = b - (2 * (b \ 2))
    If c = 0 Then
        If a = 0 Then
            DSws.Range("A" & i - 3, "H" & i). _
            Interior.Color = RGB(141, 180, 227)
            b = b + 1
            MsgBox b
        End If
    End If

Next I
```

lRow determines the last row and therefore sets the range for the loop.

After that I use two mod functions, the first to determine that it is an interval of 5, and the second to determine if the iteration is even or odd (to accomplish the other 5 effect).

When I run this code only the first 5 are highlighted.

Comment: You mean *1-5, **11**-15* right?

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what the rest of your code is intended to accomplish but this rewrite simplifies your loop to color alternating 5 row bands in columns A:H.

```
For i = 1 To lRow step 10
    DSws.cells(i, "A").resize(5, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(141, 180, 227)
Next i
```

Comment: thanks this worked well! I just had to tweak it a little but the gist was the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want, but it sounds like you want alternating colors (ie a greenbar effect for old dot matrix printer users), where every five rows alternates colors.

If that's the case, the following small modification might do that for you:

```
  Dim lrow, i, switch As Integer
  Dim DSws As Worksheet
  Dim col1, col2 As Long

  Set DSws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  switch = 0
  lrow = ???  ' assuming you have a way of defining this

  col1 = RGB(141, 180, 227)  ' Pick a color
  col2 = RGB(0, 180, 227)    ' Pick another color

  For i = 1 To lrow

    If i Mod 5 = 1 Then
      switch = switch + 1
    End If

    If switch Mod 2 = 0 Then
      DSws.Range("A" & i, "H" & i).Interior.Color = col1
    Else
      DSws.Range("A" & i, "H" & i).Interior.Color = col2
    End If

  Next i
```